# Showing solid colors in 3D waterfall graph in Octave instead of just wires

Tags: graph, octave, waterfall, shading

I am trying to make waterfall graphs in the newest version of Octave that has a solid color under each trace (this might not be the best way to describe what I am trying to do, sorry if my vocabulary is not quite correct here). Basically I want the latest version of Octave to behave with waterfall graphs the way that it used to a few years ago when you used the 'shading faceted' line.

Here are some examples using this code:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-3:.125:3);
Z = peaks(X,Y);
waterfall(X,Y,Z)
```

In Octave 4.0, that code produced this graph:
[default waterfall graph octave 4.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVBqa.jpg)

But when you add the line "shading faceted" so that the code looks like this:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-3:.125:3);
Z = peaks(X,Y);
waterfall(X,Y,Z)
shading interp;
```

That code produces this graph in Octave 4.0:
[waterfall graph with "shading faceted" octave 4.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ERZK.jpg)

The problem is, that "shading faceted" line makes no difference in newer versions of Octave- it all looks just like that first graph. So how do I make waterfall graphs look like the "shading faceted" graph from Octave 4.0 BUT in new versions of Octave?

Comment: (presumably shading interp in the code is a typo?)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a regression bug. I would encourage you to file a [bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=octave).

However, I think you can obtain what you need by changing the "edgecolor" and "facecolor" properties directly. e.g.

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-3:.125:3);
Z = peaks(X,Y);
H = waterfall(X,Y,Z);
set( H, 'facecolor', 'flat');
set( H, 'edgecolor', [0.4,0.4,0.4]);
```

[image]

You can check what other values are supported for these properties [here](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Surface-Properties.html#Surface-Properties)

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking it was a bug that developed in later versions that got overlooked as well. However, your solution is definitely helpful, so thanks again!